# Why not directly use object properties in Equals()?

Tags: c#, .net, equality

I'm busy adapting my own branch of the MS assembly `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` to use NHibernate, and I notice an incredible amount of code like the following:

```
var userId = user.Id;
var roleId = role.Id;
return await _userRoles.AnyAsync(ur => ur.RoleId.Equals(roleId) && ur.UserId.Equals(userId)).WithCurrentCulture();
```

Why not just use this?

```
return await _userRoles.AnyAsync(ur => ur.RoleId.Equals(role.Id) && ur.UserId.Equals(user.Id)).WithCurrentCulture();
```

Comment: does the 2nd code give some error or simply returns null?

Comment: Are these calls against the database? Perhaps avoiding accessing a value through a variable allows the query plan to be cached more easily.

Comment: @ArijitMukherjee No, it appears to work the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `user.Id` *may very well* change before `AnyAsync` turns the expression into SQL. There's no guarantee that the expression is evaluated immediately, and such it makes sense to reference a temporary local variable.

It might make sense to not generate the SQL until a connection has been made to the database, for example.